# HashMap within Hashmap giving different results which is not expected

Tags: java, hashmap

I am expecting result like 
`AA0={A0=0}, AA1={A1=1}, AA2={A2=2}, AA3={A3=3}, AA4={A4=4}`

but with below code I am getting result -

`{AA4={A2=2, A1=1, A4=4, A3=3, A0=0}, AA2={A2=2, A1=1, A4=4, A3=3, A0=0}, AA3={A2=2, A1=1, A4=4, A3=3, A0=0}, AA0={A2=2, A1=1, A4=4, A3=3, A0=0}, AA1={A2=2, A1=1, A4=4, A3=3, A0=0}}`

Am I doing something wrong in the code? What I am seeing during debug is when for loop is run second time, `hashMap1` contains `{AA0={A1=1}}` even before `hashMap1.put("AA"+i,hashMap2)` is executed. I am not sure why this is happening. Can someone please help me understand this?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class testingMapList {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> hashMap1 = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {   
            hashMap2.clear();     
            hashMap2.put("A"+i, i);                 
            hashMap1.put("AA"+i, hashMap2);
        }

        System.out.println("HashMap1--->"+hashMap1.get("AA").containsValue("A=4"));

    }

}
```

Comment: You're reusing the same hash map.

Comment: thanks..working now. But why does not clear work?

Comment: @S_T clear does work, but remember, you are using the same `Hashmap`. So what happens is that in the end, you have `hashMap1` containing 5 references to the same `hashMap2`, which in your last loop, you clear once and then fill with A0=0 to A4=4.

Comment: I should add that in your code, you couldn't even tell if .clear didn't work - as you insert things with the same keys (A0 to A4) every time, even if you left out the .clear, the map entries would just get overwritten, and your result would look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code snippet should suffice your requirement.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> hash = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
        HashMap<String, Integer> insideHash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        insideHash.put("A"+i, i);
        hash.put("AA"+i, insideHash);
    }
    System.out.println(hash);
}
```

result in

```
{AA0={A0=0}, AA1={A1=1}, AA2={A2=2}, AA3={A3=3}, AA4={A4=4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the same `hashMap2`. Create a new one inside the loop instead of clearing it:

```
hashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
```

Even better, declare the variable inside the loop, then there is no risk of reusing the map accidentally (via that variable).